# dynamic UItableviewcell still show placeholder text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, datasource

I have embedded a dynamic UITableView inside a static cell.

I have also created a new data source based on the answer to this question: Swift: TableView within Static UITableViewCell

My problem is that the data for the dynamic UITableViewcell is not loading data and keeping show the placeholder name. Can you help me understand why?

the main view Controller

```
class CreateCompanyTableViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var lblNumberOfUser: UILabel!
var newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder] = []
private lazy var dataSource = NewUserDataSource(newStakeholders: self.newStakeholders)

@IBOutlet weak var companyUsersTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   
    super.viewDidLoad()
    lblNumberOfUser.text = "\(newStakeholders.count) Users"
    companyUsersTableView.dataSource = dataSource
    companyUsersTableView.delegate = dataSource
    companyUsersTableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    lblNumberOfUser.text = "\(newStakeholders.count) Users"
    companyUsersTableView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func addNewUser(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueAddNewUsers", sender: sender)
}

@IBAction func unwindFromSelectSubUsertoAddUserCompany(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue){
    if  let senderVC = sender.source as? NewUserForCompanyTableViewController{
        print(senderVC.newStakeholder!)
        var newuser = senderVC.newStakeholder!
        dataSource.newStakeholders.append(newuser)
        companyUsersTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}

[image]

```
class NewUserDataSource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate{
    // We keep this public and mutable, to enable our data
    // source to be updated as new data comes in.
    var newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder]
    
    init(newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder]) {
        self.newStakeholders = newStakeholders
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newStakeholders.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let stakeholders = newStakeholders[indexPath.row]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: "newUserTableViewCell",
            for: indexPath
            ) as! NewUserTableViewCell
        
        cell.setlblUsername(stakeholders.fullName)
        cell.setlblEmail(stakeholders.emailAddress!)
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: please check if the delegate methods are getting called ?

Comment: Please set delegate tableview in your view controller

Comment: I have set the delegate tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like your data is empty:

```
    var newStakeholders: [ReadOrganizationStakeholder] = []
```

You've commented this:

```
       // let dataSource = NewUserDataSource(newStakeholders: self.newStakeholders)
```

So being empty, this returns 0

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return newStakeholders.count
    }
```

Set a breakpoint there and debug, please

Comment: My show newStakeholders.count is 1 when I create a new user but assign to labels is not working ?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` seems like you're trying to print in the labels before 1st creating `dataSource` (`lazy` means that won't be init until you access that). Then, you access that but `newStakeholders` has been set to `[]` and you print that empty count in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Either move `    lblNumberOfUser.text = "\(newStakeholders.count) Users"` to the bottom of `viewDidLoad` or remove that `lazy` attribute

Comment: if I remove the lazy I will get error  "Value of type '(CreateCompanyTableViewController) -> () -> CreateCompanyTableViewController' has no member 'newStakeholders'"